How to get session id and caller id in flexible webhook in dialogflow cx?
I am creating a small flask app with dialogflow cx and I would like to use flexible webhooks but the problem is I am unable to get the session_id and caller_id when I use flexible. Other params I can access using $session.params.variable_name. Any idea how I can access these two variables?
{
  "doctor_name": "$session.params.doctor_name",
  "patient_name": "$session.params.patient_name",
  "caller_id": "$session.params.caller_id",
  "session_id": "$session"
}

I tried this, here the caller_id wouldn't work and session_id as well as they are not present. How do I pass these two in the webhook request?

@app.route('/api/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():

    print(f"Data: {request.get_data()}")

    return make_fulfillment_message('some dummy response here'), 200


You need to reference $request.session-id
See https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#request-built-in for more details

For session id yes, it works but got any idea for caller id in flexible webhook? Also Thanks for the answer!

@DilipBadal Sorry I am not sure how to get caller id. Is this showing on your parameters list in the context of the webhook call? You can check it using the standard webhook type to troubleshoot and request to a test API locally (I suggest using ngrok to expose publicly).

Yeh, I figured as much as I could not find anything related to it, I am using standard webhooks to get the caller id and then make another webhook call in the next intent which will be flexible. Thanks alot though
